# Magento 2.3.2 : Site is down every time I install a new extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, permissions

Whenever I upload a new extension to my app/code folder, the site goes systematically down.
I upload it using the magento user so there is no owner issue.
I am in production mode.

More specifically this happens just after registering the extension:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Here is the error msg in the browser:

> An error has happened during application run. See exception log for
>   details.

I solve the issue the following way:

```
rm -rf ./var/cache/ ./var/pages_cache/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
rm -rf ./var/cache/
```

Then restart varnish and invalidate cdn cache.

**However** I would really like to solve the underlying issue.

And here is the log exception at the same time:

> [2019-08-25 11:14:04] main.CRITICAL: Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist
>   {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist at
>   /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"}
>   []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Magento. when you have run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command then all **cache ,pages_cache and static content and Code compiler** are clear that why you are getting error**

> An error has happened during application run. See exception log for
>   details.

At production mode, ***Magento does not auto-generate static content, class compilation***, So after running setup upgrade command, you need to run below command.

- `php bin/magento setup:di:compile for [Code compileation]`[1](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html).
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy for Static content
  deploy`.

So, the best way to install an extension or run the setup upgrade, you first need to  Enable Maintenance mode. then run the following commands.

**Steps should be the following:**

1. `Enable Maintenance mode by`**`php bin/magento maintenance:enable`**
2. `Enable extension by`**`php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName`**
3. `Run Setup Upgrade`**`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`**.
4. `Run di compilation`**`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`**.
5. `Run Static content deploy`**`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`**.
6. `Disable Maintenance mode by`**`php bin/magento maintenance:disable`**.